# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'contoh.dbo.data'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
alter PROCEDURE Createdata  
prosedur
        @nama varchar(20),  
        @alamat varchar(50)      
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION  
declare @id int  
INSERT INTO data  (nama, alamat)
    VALUES (@nama,@alamat)

SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  
SELECT 
       nama = @nama,
       alamat = @alamat
FROM data 

WHERE  ID = @id

COMMIT  
GO
```

==============================================

please help me, i use this store procedure in another database its work
but i run this store procedure in database "contoh" doesn't work

eror is :

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table
>   'contoh.dbo.data'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

Comment: Seems like the id column is declare as not null, but has no default value.

Comment: You have to search on the constraints of your table if the column ID is nullable and change it.

Comment: i was use :: 
ALTER TABLE data  
   ADD ID INT IDENTITY

Comment: @f0xs what you mean?

Comment: You have to see the structure of your table. Your ID column may be a primary key or a column that can not be null. If it does, your procedure will never work unless you insert an id or add the ID with an auto increment.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the `Id` column doesn't allow null values and you didn't specify it when apply insert.

```
INSERT INTO data  (nama, alamat) VALUES (@nama,@alamat)
```

I guess, `Id` column is primary key and you could define it as auto increment. So, create your table by using `IDENTITY(1,1)` to apply auto increment for `Id` column;

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    nama nvarchar(20),
    alamat nvarchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `AUTO_INCREMENT` is valid (MS) SQL server keyword. `IDENTITY` could be used here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
INSERT INTO data (nama, alamat) VALUES (@nama,@alamat)
```

`data` has column id and it is your primary key and therefore cannot be created with NULL as its value.  You probably meant to grab the id beforehand and then call:

```
INSERT INTO data (id, nama, alamat) VALUES (@id,@nama,@alamat)
```